# Java sorted array output into linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

is there a way to sort an array and store the result in a linked list with the original array positions referenced by the list?

so

0 bbb
1 aaa
2 ccc

would become a linked list

1 aaa
0 bbb
2 ccc

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want the array positions preserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyClass[] array = new MyClass[n];
// fill the array
Arrays.sort(array);
List<MyClass> list = new LinkedList<Class>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `TreeMap`:

```
final SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(array.length);

for (int index = 0; index < array.length; i++)
    map.put(array[index], index);
```

The keys are therefore the strings, in order, and the positions in the original aray are the values. But storing a String *and* its origin position requires a dedicated structure. Or maybe the `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` entries for the map are enough for your needs. It depends on what you want to do.